# postgreSQL select interval and fill blanks

Tags: postgresql, intervals

I'm working on a system to manage the problems in different projects.

I have the following tables:

**Projects**

| id | Description | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3D experience | Brazil |
| 2 | Lorem Epsum | Chile |

**Problems**

| id | idProject | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Not loading |
| 2 | 1 | Breaking down |

**Problems_status**

| id | idProblem | Status | Start_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Red | 2020-10-17 | 2020-10-25 |
| 2 | 1 | Yellow | 2020-10-25 | 2020-11-20 |
| 3 | 1 | Red | 2020-11-20 |  |
| 4 | 2 | Red | 2020-11-01 | 2020-11-25 |
| 5 | 2 | Yellow | 2020-11-25 | 2020-12-22 |
| 6 | 2 | Red | 2020-12-22 | 2020-12-23 |
| 7 | 2 | Green | 2020-12-23 |  |

In the above examples, the problem 1 is still red, and the problem 2 is green (no end date).

I need to create a chart when the user selects an specific project, where the status of the problems along the weeks (starting by the week of the first registered problem) will be shown. The chart of the project 1 should look like this:
[image]

I'm trying to write a code in postgreSQL to return a table like this, so that I can populate this chart:

| Week | Green | Yellow | Red |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42/20 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 43/20 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 44/20 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 04/21 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I've been trying multiple ways but just can't figure out how to do that, could someone help me please?
Bellow a db-fiddle to help:

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  description character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  country character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT projects_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE problems (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  id_project integer NOT NULL,
  description character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT problems_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT problems_id_project_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_project)
      REFERENCES projects (id) MATCH SIMPLE
);

CREATE TABLE problems_status (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  id_problem integer NOT NULL,
  status character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  start_date date NOT NULL,
  end_date date,
  CONSTRAINT problems_status_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT problems_status_id_problem_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_problem)
      REFERENCES problems (id) MATCH SIMPLE
);

INSERT INTO projects (description, country) VALUES ('3D experience','Brazil');
INSERT INTO projects (description, country) VALUES ('Lorem Epsum','Chile');
INSERT INTO problems (id_project ,description) VALUES (1,'Not loading');
INSERT INTO problems (id_project ,description) VALUES (1,'Breaking down');
INSERT INTO problems_status (id_problem, status, start_date, end_date) VALUES
(1, 'Red', '2020-10-17', '2020-10-25'),(1, 'Yellow', '2020-10-25', '2020-11-20'),
(1, 'Red', '2020-11-20', NULL),(2, 'Red', '2020-11-01', '2020-11-25'),
(2, 'Yellow', '2020-11-25', '2020-12-22'),(2, 'Red', '2020-12-22', '2020-12-23'),
(2, 'Green', '2020-12-23', NULL);
```

Comment: what is the logic behind week as x/y in desired output ?

Comment: It's the weeknumber (like in excel formula) and the year: Week 42 Year 2020 = 42/20

Comment: it would be easy to help if you could setup a db fiddle

Comment: @HarshGundecha just created the db-fiddle to help! =)

Comment: Sorry, another update, I can have more than one status change within a week. In this cases, I need to consider only the latest one... (added a 7th row to the problems_status table as an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your goal is to produce a weekly tally by problem status for a particular project for a specific time period (Min db date to current date). Further if a problem status spans week then is should be included in each weeks tally.  That involve 2 time periods, the report period against the status start/end dates and checking for overlap of those dates. Now there ate 5 overlaps scenarios that need checking; lets call the ranges let A the any week in the report period and B. the start/end of status. Now, allowing that A must end  within the reporting period. but B does not we have the following.

- A starts, B starts, A ends, B ends.  B overlaps end of A.
- A starts, B starts, B ends, A ends.  B totally contained within A.
- B starts, A starts, B ends, A ends.  B overlaps start of A.
- B starts, A starts, A ends, B ends.  A totally enclosed within B.
  Fortunately, Postgres provides functionally to handle all the above meaning the query does not have to handle the individual validations. This is [DATERANGE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html)s and the Overlap operator. The difficult work then becomes defining each week with in A. Then employ the Overlap operator on daterange for each week in A against the daterange for B (start_date, end_date). Then do conditional aggregation. for each overlap detected.   See full [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=07daa673d8f0ec8956536143e6fae7de).

```
with  problem_list( problem_id ) as 
       -- identify the specific problem_ids desirded
       (select ps.id 
          from projects p
          join problems ps on(ps.id_project =  p.id)
         where p.id  = &selected_project
       )  --select * from problem_list;
      
  , report_period(srange, erange) as 
       -- generate the first day of week (Mon) for the
       -- oldest start date through day of week of Current_Date   
       (select min(first_of_week(ps.start_date))  
             , first_of_week(current_date)
          from problem_status ps
          join problem_list pl 
            on (pl.problem_id = ps.id_problem)
       )  --select * from report_period; 
      
  , weekly_calendar(wk,yr, week_dates) as 
       -- expand the start, end date ranges to week dates (Mon-Sun) 
       -- and identify the week number with year
       (select extract( week from mon)::integer wk
             , extract( isoyear from mon)::integer yr
             , daterange(mon, mon+6, '[]'::text) wk_dates
          from (select generate_series(srange,erange, interval '7 days')::date mon
                  from  report_period
               ) d
       )  -- select * from weekly_calendar; 
   , status_by_week(yr,wk,status) as   
     -- determine where problem start_date, end_date overlaps each calendar week
     -- then where multiple statuses exist for any week keep only the lat               
        ( select yr,wk,status  
            from (select  wc.yr,wc.wk,ps.status 
                 --   ,  ps.start_date, wc.week_dates,id_problem 
                      , row_number() over (partition by ps.id_problem,yr,wk order by yr, wk, start_date desc)  rn
                   from problem_status  ps 
                    join problem_list   pl on (pl.problem_id = ps.id_problem)
                    join weekly_calendar wc on (wc.week_dates && daterange(ps.start_date,ps.end_date))  -- actual overlap test  
                 ) ac
           where rn=1
        ) -- select * from status_by_week order by wk;
select 'Project ' || p.id || ': ' || p.description Project
    , to_char(wk,'fm09') || '/' || substr(to_char(yr,'fm0000'),3) "WK"
    , "Red", "Yellow", "Green"
 from projects p
cross join (select sbw.yr,sbw.wk 
                 , count(*) filter (where sbw.status = 'Red')    "Red"
                 , count(*) filter (where sbw.status = 'Yellow') "Yellow"
                 , count(*) filter (where sbw.status = 'Green')  "Green" 
              from status_by_week sbw 
             group by sbw.yr, sbw.wk
           ) sr
where p.id  = &selected_project
order by yr,wk;
```

The CTEs and main operate as follows:

- *problem_list*: Identifies the Problems (id_problem) related the
  specified project.
- *report_period*: Identifies the full reporting period start to end.
- *weekly_calendar*: Generates the beginning date (Mon) and ending date   (Sun) for each week within the reporting period (A above). Along the
  way it also gathers week of the year and the ISO year.
- *status_by_week*: This is the real work horse preforming two tasks.
  First is passes each problem by each of the week in the calendar. It
  builds row for each overlap detected. Then it enforces the "one
  status" rule.
- Finally, the main select aggregates the status into the appropriate
  buckets and adds the syntactic sugar getting the Program Name.

Note the function *first_of_week()*. This is a user defined function and available in the example and below. I created it some time ago and have found it useful. You are free to use it. But you do so **without any claim of suitability or guaranty**.

```
create or replace
function first_of_week(date_in date)
 returns date
language sql
immutable strict
/*
 * Given a date return the first day of the week according to ISO-8601
 * 
 *    ISO-8601 Standard (in short) 
 *    1 All weeks begin on Monday.
 *    2 All Weeks have exactly 7 days.
 *    3 First week of any year is the Monday on or before 4-Jan.
 *      This implies that the last few days on Dec may be in the 
 *      first week of the following year and that the first few 
 *      days of Jan may be in week 53 (53) of the prior year.
 *      (Not at the same time obviously.)  
 *  
 */ 
as $$
   with wk_adj(l_days) as (values  (array[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]))
   select date_in - l_days[ extract (isodow from date_in)::integer ]
     from wk_adj;
$$;
```

In the example I have implemented the query as a SQL function as it seems db<>fiddle has issues with bound variables
and substitution variables, Besides it gave the ability to parameterize it. (Hate hard coded values). For the example I
added additional data fro extra testing, Mostly as data that will not be selected.  And an additional Status (what happens if it encounters something other than those 3 status values (in this case Pink). This easy to remove, just get rid on OTHER.

---

Your notice that "the daterange is covering mon-mon, instead of mon-sun" is incorrect, although it would appear that way for someone not use to looking at them. Lets take week 43. If you queried the date range it would show  [2020-10-19,2020-10-26) and yes both those dates are Monday. However, the bracketing characters have meaning. The leading character [ says the date **is to included** and the trailing character ) says the date **is not to be included**. A standard condition:

```
somedate && [2020-10-19,2020-10-26) 
is the same as
somedate >= 2020-10-19 and somedate < 2020-10-26
```

This is why when you change the increment from "mon+6" to "mon+5" you *fixed* week 43, but introduced errors into other weeks.

Comment: Thanks @Belayer! There's still one point though... for some reason in weeks 43 and 44, it's counting 1 red and 1 yellow point, but as a matter of fact it should be only 1 yellow point on both weeks 43 and 44 (I'm trying to find inside your code why is it happening). Maybe that's because the problem 1 is red from week 42 until the last day (sunday) of week 43, and this point go to yellow from the sunday (of week 43) until week 47. As we have this change of status exactly on the sunday, it looks like the code is counting it twice maybe? We can see something similar at week 47

Comment: I agree week 43 should have only the 1 Yellow (from problem status id 2).  However, I do not think "counting it twice" is the problem.  It seems the keep only latest status rule fails  to exclude the Red from (from problem status id 1).  I am leaning toward needing to perform this check after the overlap operator. See code section just after  "*from (-- when problem has multiple statuses ...*". Sorry I did not have opportunity to look earlier, and unfortunately it's quite late now in central US. Perhaps tomorrow.

Comment: No problem hehe here in Brazil it's early now =) I figured out that the daterange is covering mon-mon, instead of mon-sun. I changed the "mon+6" to "mon+5" and it solved the point of week 43. The problem now is that on week 47 for example, it's counting the red status as it ends in the middle of the week, and also the yellow status (of the same problem) as it starts in the middle of the week. I'll try to use the "row_number partition by" once more to exclude this kind of overlap!

Comment: unfortunately the version of the database I'm using is the 9.0 and there isn't a daterange function available, do you know any workaround for that?

Comment: @ViníciusOllitta I have update the my answer and the example. It turns out I was correct that performing the overlay operation before the single status per week rule was necessary. I also show why your change form "mon+6" to "mon+5", while apparently logical, was incorrect.  But I am confused if the version you are using doesn't have daterange how are you running it at all?  As far as a work around I know of none than writing code. Now Postgres 9.0 reached end-of-lift 5years 5months ago ( Oct 2015). I suggest it is way past time for you to update.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill in blanks using `COALESCE` to select the first non-null value in the list.

```
SELECT COALESCE(<some_value_that_could_be_null>, <some_value_that_will_not_be_null>);
```

If you want to force the bounds of your time range into a result set you can `UNION` your result set with a specific date.

```
SELECT ... -- your data query here
UNION ALL
SELECT end_ts -- WHERE end_ts is a timestamptz type
```

In order to `UNION` you will need to have the same arity and same type of fields returned in the unioned query. You can fill in everything other than the timestamp with `NULL` casted to whichever the matching type is.

More concrete example:

```
WITH data AS -- get raw data
(
    SELECT p.id
         , ps.status
         , ps.start_date
         , COALESCE(ps.end_date, CURRENT_DATE, '01-01-2025'::DATE) -- you can fill in NULL values with COALESCE
         , pj.country
         , pj.description
         , MAX(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY p.id) AS latest_update
      FROM problems p
      JOIN projects pj ON (pj.id = p.id_project)
      JOIN problem_status ps ON (p.id = ps.id_problem)
     UNION ALL -- force bounds in the following
    SELECT NULL::INTEGER -- could be null or a defaulted value
         , NULL::TEXT    -- could be null or a defaulted value
         , start_date -- either as an input param to a function or a hard-coded date
         , end_date   -- either as an input param to a function or a hard-coded date
         , NULL::TEXT
         , NULL::TEXT
         , NULL::DATE
) -- aggregate in the following
SELECT <week> -- you'll have to figure out how you're getting weeks out of the DATE data
     , COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'Red')
     , COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'Yellow')
     , COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'Green')
  FROM data
 WHERE start_date = latest_update
 GROUP BY <week> 
;
```

---

Some of the features used in this query are very powerful and you should look them up if they're new to you and you are going to be doing a bunch of reporting queries. Mainly coalesce, common table expressions (CTE), window functions, and aggregate expressions.

[Aggregate Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

[WITH Queries (CTEs)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html)

[COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)

[Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-window.html)

---

I wrote a dbfiddle for you to take a look at [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=39972449afae96b2766640a4b6fb5fd4) after you updated your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! to manage the week part, I'm thinking on:
SELECT DATE_PART('week',i::date) FROM generate_series('2020-10-17', 
  CURRENT_DATE, '1 week'::interval) i;
I'm trying to figure out now though how to fill this generated table, since in the example on the first 3 weeks I'll have only one red point, but after the 4th week there are 2 points, and so on...

Comment: @ViníciusOllitta I've updated the answer with a link to a dbfiddle which accounts for the `DATE_PART` and `generate_series`.

Comment: @ViníciusOllitta I should warn that if you are using `DATE_PART('week', ...)` that it may not make much sense when you rollover a year in one report. You'll have something like weeks `1, 2, 43, 44, ..., 52`.

Comment: Thanks @J Spratt! the retuned table doesn't show though the status properly. For example, in weeks 45 and 46 it show no points, where we actually already have one problem on going. That means, it needs to count red for a point all the next weeks, until it's turned into another color (e.g. yellow or green), and than count this new color until the next change, and so on..